# Exporting sequence file to Oracle by Sqoop

Tags: oracle, hadoop, sqoop, hcatalog, sequencefile

I have been trying to find some documentations about how we can export sequence file to Oracle by using Sqoop. Is that possible?

Currently I have my files(in HDFS) in text based format and I am using Sqoop to export those files to some Oracle's tables and its working fine. Now I want to change the format of the file from text to sequence file or something else (Avro later). So what I need to do if I want to export different file format from HDFS to Oracle using Sqoop?

Any information will be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, export of sequence files is not supported by Sqoop at the moment.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. Is there any work-around? Just to export data to Oracle (assume the result is generating by a MR job), I have to output it in regular text based format?

Though I haven't used HCatalog, but read somewhere (may be I misunderstood), that if I create schema in HCatalog, then I can use any format for exporting/importing data and can also plug Sqoop there? Or is that true for only Hive? Thanks again.

Comment: Any chance you can use Avro files? Export is supported there, it has all the benefits of binary format, compression and Hive integration.

Comment: Yes, I can use Avro, since I was already using sequence files for the input portion of my MR jobs, I thought I will first try with sequence file and then Avro. Could you please guide me a good documentations or tutorials which shows exporting avro files to Oracle by sqoop? Thank you once again for your response.

Answer (score 1):

This may not help to export the data to **oracle Db**. But just thought of putting it over here as sqoop supports export of sequence file - just check this - 
[Sqoop export for sequence file](https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/37351/unable-to-export-a-sequence-file-to-mysql-using-sq.html)